# Why can't I see the polygon drawn in this svg and how can I make it visible?

Tags: javascript, svg

Background: I'm letting users draw on a GoogleMap and I'm then pulling the points they draw from it to make an svg that the users can name and reference later. This seems to be working when those drawings are large enough, but I seem to have a problem when they are very small (like a polygon around a small park for example).

You can play with a version of this here: https://codepen.io/glenpierce/pen/MRqwmJ?editors=1010

When I go to inspect the actual polygons within the svgs, they appear to be placed within the viewBox and I think they should be visible, but I can't get them to appear. When I set the svgs stroke to any width above 0, the stroke completely takes over the entire viewBox. I thought svgs were "scalable". Are there some rules about very small decimal values or anything? If so, where can I find a reference to that?

**Is there a way to scale (or otherwise fix) the polygon in this svg in vanilla JS to make it visible within this svg?**

```
<svg
height="180px"
width="360px"
viewBox="
92.52881560431149
43.41319404777748
0.0024139881134033203
0.00027281812062796007

"><polygon points="
92.5290516387048,
43.41319404777748,
92.53095064268734,
43.4132456619112,
92.53122959242489,
43.413400504607246,
92.52903018103268,
43.41346686589811,
92.52881560431149,
43.4132087946678
"></polygon></svg>
```

note: I've edited the spacing on this to make it easier to read.

[image: how it looks in codepen]

See above how this works on the triangle in green, but you can see that I have highlighted the rectangle that is not visible in the other svg.

Comment: I do not recognize the syntax of your x1, y1 x2, y2 point values in your polygon. each value ends with a comma, while the pairs X, Y must be separated by a space character

Comment: @MrJ I tried removing the commas, but that doesn't seem to change anything. I've also got other svgs that have such commas and they do appear (but I'll look at removing those commas in my JS anyways since it's making it harder to read, thank you for pointing that out to me)

Comment: the only way to scale a SVG is in the  viewBox values [ posX, posY, Width , Height ];  the Width , Height of the viewbox as to be compared to the css Width , Height to make a zoom or a reduce

Comment: then you have to see about preserve​Aspect​Ratio https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, it seems that something is happening when the svg and/or viewBox is too small.

Comment: So, maybe multiply by 1000 (or more)  all yours points values ?

Comment: I'm happy to do that, but then I'll have to do some math with the viewBox, any idea what that geometry/algebra would look like? Even so, why do I need to do that and what is the limitation of the svg specification in this case? Users might make something so small that I need to multiply it by 10,000 or 100,000, where do I need to set the boundaries for it?

Comment: It seems he doesn't like your polygon points, and they have strange values for myself, maybe they are outside numeric precision ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that svgs have precision limitations: "Using single-precision floats, SVG viewers are not expected to correctly draw differences between two values finer than 1/4,000,000 of the larger number (that’s 1 over 2 to the power of 22, approximately). In practice, very few achieve even that."

source: https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch08-precision.html