# SVG: Why aren't the shapes drawn inside svg visible which is on an image?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I'm working in a proyect with Angular. My goal is to draw a polygon in an image. To do this, I put an svg inside the image. The img and the svg has a width and height and the polygon's points are in the database, so their value can't change. The problem is that the polygon doesn't show well. This is a little example:

[image]

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="img-map">
    <img #image src="https://content.gnoss.ws/imagenes/Documentos/ImagenesSemanticas/07aabdfa-981f-41f7-828d-78f21adb80a6/eb1d0185-7d5b-4d3a-b84a-5aefd95d3365.jpg" alt=""/>

    <svg style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <polygon class="polygonStyle" [attr.points]="stringPoints" />
    </svg>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-map {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 450px);
}

.polygonStyle {
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75);
  fill: none;
}

img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

TS:

```
stringPoints = "1015,481 1043,578 1087,565 1055,467";
```

I've done a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qwnv5v?file=src/app/app.component.ts). I suppose the problem is related to the scale but I don't know how to solve it.

**What I've tried:**

- I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55803931/13331446) in stackoverflow, but I haven't seen any valid answer.
- This [proyect](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bkjut8?file=src/app/app.component.html) includes the code with the viewbox attribute but it hasn't any effect.
  [image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: did you try putting a `position: absolute` in the child elements of the `position: relative`?

Comment: @efkah Yes, it's actually in the code I wrote. The svg has `position:absolute.`

Comment: The image has no width and height. Also you will need the svg to have the same width and height as the image but all depends on the coords in the data base.  How do those coords look like: percentages? just numbers? Also: probably you will need a viewBox attribute for the svg element if you need a responsive graphic.

Comment: @enxaneta how they are stored in the database does not matter as I transform their format to required string for the polygon. So, the stringPoints variable is the important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default view box of an SVG is 300 x 150 with an origin at 0,0. In your examples, the polygon coordinates are: 1015,481 1043,578 1087,565 1055,467. So they are all outside the visible area of the SVG. Therefore, nothing is visible.

You should set an explict view box, e.g.:

```
<svg viewBox="1000 400 100 200" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <polygon class="polygonStyle" [attr.points]="stringPoints" />
</svg>
```

It sets a view box with an origin of 1000,400 and a size of 100 by 200. Your SVG content will then be translated and scaled such that all coordinates with an x-position between 1000 and 1100 and a y-position between 400 and 600 lie within the visible area of the SVG.

So the `viewBox` attribute affects the content of the SVG. `width`, `height` and `position` on the other side do not affect the content of the SVG but rather where the SVG is shown and how big it is.

Comment: Yes. You're right. I will mark the answer as correct. Thank you.